# OEM wheel studs don't fit my car?

Tags: wheels, dealer

I have a 2009 Kia Rio, and one of the studs for a rear wheel got broken (probably the local tire shop's fault, but it's my word against their's).

I went to an auto parts store to get a replacement. However, the diameter of the end closest to the head (that actually meshes with the hub) was too small, and I could easily seat the head of the stud flush against the hub and spin it with my fingers. Obviously the wrong part.

I figured this was simply a case of the aftermarket stuff not being quite right, so I went to the dealer. They sold me an equivalent part to what I got at the auto parts store. I explained the situation, and they went around and around, but couldn't find the right part.

Any ideas for what I can do now? If the dealer can't even give me the right stud, how do I go about getting one?

Edit: Previous owner of the vehicle back that corner of the car into a concrete pole, and it had some very minor damage to the bumper, taillight, and body when I bought it. I suppose it's *possible*, though I feel highly unlikely, that there was damage to the wheel and hub, that they had an aftermarket hub put on, and that the aftermarket hub has slightly different studs? When I have a chance, I'll try to verify if this is the case...

Comment: Try that stud on the other side, that will tell you if that one hub got swapped.

Comment: Also, just for fun, there were 2 different body styles of the Kia Rio (sedan and hatchback). Try a wheel stud from the other body style, they may have different wheel hubs. Sometimes repair shops grab a wheel hub without checking if it's the correct one, because they assume Kia Rio wheel hubs are all the same for a given model year. When I do the rear brakes on my '94 Sentra, I need to ask for pads from a '92 Maxima and rotors from a '93 Pulsar, otherwise I get the wrong parts.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post is a years old but just in case anybody comes along who needs help with this. I just, in 2022, had the exact same issue. After visiting all the auto parts stores multiple times I finally found "Dorman AutoGrade M12-1.50 Thread Wheel Lug Bolt part 610-265" at O'Reilly's. It's listed as a generic wheel stud and it's a bit longer than the original ones so you'll need to get open-ended lug nuts but it works.

Comment: Wow... The fact that somebody else experienced this problem suggests that Kia just forgot what part they used in the Rio. That's kind of shocking. Thanks for sharing your findings - hope it helps somebody else. (In my case, I ended up putting on an aftermarket hub 'cause I never found a stud that would fit mine.)

Answer (score 1):

The studs for the Kia Rio appear to have a knurled shoulder that drives into the hub. The ones I found online look like this:

[image: Wheel stud with knurled area to retain stud in hub]

The ones I found spec the knurl diameter at 0.508 or 0.511 inches and claim to fit from 2003 to 2105. If you have a dial caliper try measuring the original stud, the new stud, and the hole in the hub. That should give you a feel for where the problem is.

One possibility is that the hub has been damaged and the area where the studs fit is now oversize. If the difference is significant, it is likely that the hub is either not an OE hub or that there has been a manufacturing change somewhere along the line.

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort here. The stud you found has a visibly smaller knurl diameter than the old one. This leaves me thinking that I don't have the hub I think I have (as you suggest) or that Kia mis-communicated some specs somewhere along the line. The fact that many auto parts stores list this stud only as a "front" stud suggests that the latter is a possibility. I've taken the old stud and a lug to my local hardware store and verified the thread size. I have some vernier calipers arriving today, which I'll use to get all the other dimensions. That should let me order the right part.